# Button color change using bootstrap, symfony and twig

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'am using bootstrap,symfony and twig on my website. I created btn-group in loop like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            <label class="form-check-label">Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to change the color of a `btn-primary` when checkbox in this button is selected. How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure i would put a checkbox in a button, it would probably be better to use your own custom css to control the background colour of the div.

But you could do it with some JavaScript and detect when a checkbox is checked then change the btn class. If you are loading this from an entity and a checkbox is already checked on page load then you could do it via JavaScript also by looping the check boxes.